# Set confirmation prompt box's title

Tags: javascript

Any way to set the confirmation prompt (confirm() in javascript) box's title? At the moment it will display the confirmation prompt box's title to "Windows Internet Explorer" if it run in IE and "the page at http://... said: " in Firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) nor [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536376(VS.85).aspx) support setting a title, as indicated in the linked specs.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible according to specs. May I suggest that you use a [JavaScript modal box](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=javascript+modal+box) instead.

I've used [wildbit labs' Modalbox](http://www.wildbit.com/labs/modalbox/) which works quite well.