# Change title of alert boxes on web apps?

Tags: popup, web-applications

Pretty straightforward question: On web apps they force the title of the popup to be the URL of the website. Is there any way to change this to a custom title? Or do you I have to do this in JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title) and [Change Title of Javascript Alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172022/change-title-of-javascript-alert) and [problem with javascirpt for change the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090180/problem-with-javascirpt-for-change-the-title) and [Set confirmation prompt box's title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724271/set-confirmation-prompt-boxs-title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh...no you can't.

Its a security/anti-phishing feature.